# Jsoup messing the HTML with self closing text area

Tags: jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to change an HTML a little and this HTML has some parts that are injected by the publishers of the site.
There's something strange happening when parsing the HTML.
Whenever it has a self closing text area (which I know is invalid, but the publishers sometimes do that), the following elements are escaped, as they were part of the text area, like so:

```html
<div>
<div>
<textarea/>
</div>
</div>
```

Becomes

```html
<div>
<div>
<textarea></textarea>
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

I would expect it to become:

```html
<div>
<div>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there something I could do to avoid that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use XML parser so Jsoup doesn't try to fix HTML syntax.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div><div><textarea/></div></div>", "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Comment: Well, I do want it to fix the HTML syntax. In the end, I'm still generating an HTML. So, I want it to fix the syntax. I just don't want it to assume anything after the self-closing text area to be *inside* the text area (and, thus, be escaped).

Comment: Seems it's a bug anyway. I reported it here https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1220